# MAMP mysql install directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mamp, mysql2

I can not find the install directories for mysql under MAMP. I have used WAMP before, and I easily found the folders where mysql were installed. Not so much with MAMP. I can't find this anywhere on the inter webs either.

What I am doing is installing the mysql2 gem for use with ruby on rails. To do this I apparently need to run this script:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 --version=0.2.6 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Thus I need the different folder locations in the above script. Anyone know where to find these folders?

I use OSX Lion, Ruby 0.8.7, rails 3.0.0, Aptana Studio 3.

Comment: I think it *might* be located at `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/` I'm not on the computer I have it installed on. But if not there, it should be somewhere in the `/Applications/MAMP/*` folder

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and fixed it installing MySQL using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), period. I still use MAMP for WordPress and PHP websites, though.

It's a bit of a hassle the start/stop the thing but I do that with MAMP anyway... It's too much headache to make this gem work normally with MAMP...

Comment: Can you get phpMyAdmin with the homebrew mysql?